# Can HP blade server/any server units be run as stand alone workstation?

Tags: hp, blade-server, blade-chassis

I am new to the Server Hardware world?

My question is very basic and might be absurd. Since I haven't had the opportunity to work on blades yet. 
**Can HP blade server units/any other blade server units be run as stand alone workstation?**
for reference such as HP BL490c or any other. Since I am planning to buy one used from ebay. So I wished to make sure that I can run the unit as Desktop/Workstation/server.

What

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They cannot. The blade server requires an enclosure in order to provide power, networking and downplane/backplane connections. It is useless without this.

Comment: Does these blade server units inside blade chassis work as an independent server and Are OSes installed individually on units or Do these multiple blade units make one server as in one server in chassis.

Comment: Blades are not complete computers. You need a chassis to make them work. Some blades have their own storage, some don't.